# SQL query for finding pairs that share some values but not others

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Im having some trouble creating a query for this problem.

I need to find which pairs of people have `WorkedOn` Build with each other but have not `Financed` them together.

My table:

```
Build(person, financed, workedOn)

Person | Financed | WorkedOn
-----------------------------
Person1| Build1   | Build4
Person2| Build2   | Build5
Person3| Build1   | Build5
Person4| Build2   | Build3
Person5| Build3   | Build1
Person6| Build1   | Build5
Person7| Build4   | Build3
Person8| Build5   | Build3
```

The correct query should produce something like this:

```
Person
-------
Person7  Person8
Person8  Person4
Person6  Person3
```

Ive tried using `distinct` and `having` I just dont seem to be getting it right. Any help would be appreciated, Im using sqlite3, thank you :)

Comment: In your example should Person6  Person3 be in the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **self join**.

Here is the [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d385/11)

**Input** : [image]

**Output**:
[image]

```
SELECT T1.Person,T2.Person,CONCAT(T1.Person,' ',T2.Person) AS Person
    FROM
          Build T1 
    INNER JOIN 
          Build T2 
    ON T1.WorkedOn = T2.WorkedOn AND T1.Financed <> T2.Financed 
   WHERE T1.Person < T2.Person
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, that's my version slightly refactored?! :)

Comment: Why duplicate the OP's database contents?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.person, t2.person
FROM build t1, build t2
WHERE t1.workedon = t2.workedon
AND t1.financed != t2.financed
AND t1.person > t2.person
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d385/9)